# How to implement a type eraser for std::function like classes?

Tags: c++, type-erasure, std-function

I want to put several method pointers in a container, so I implemented a simple `std::function`- like template class:

```
template<typename ...Args>
class MethodHolder : MethodHolderBase
{
public:
    typedef void(*MethodType)(Args...);
    MethodHolder(MethodType method) : method(method) {}
    virtual ~MethodHolder() {}

    void Invoke(Args... args)
    { method(args...); }

private:
    MethodType method;
};
```

It has a base class so I can write code like this:

```
void func(int);
...
std::vector<MethodHolderBase*> funcs;
funcs.push_back(new MethodHolder<int>(&func));
...
```

Then I add a wrapper to call `Invoke()` from `MethodHolderBase`:

```
class Method
{
public:
    ...//constructors, assignment operator, destructor
    template<typename ...Args>
    void Invoke(Args&&... args)
    {
        auto pHolder = dynamic_cast<MethodHolder<Args...>*>(pBase);
        if (pHolder)
            pHolder->Invoke(args...);
    }
private:
    MethodHolderBase* pBase;
}
```

Now, I can put some instances of Method in a container, and call `Invoke()` to call a function. It worked. But once I changed the declaration of `func` to:

```
void func(int&&);
```

It seems like no matter which type I pass to `Method::Invoke()`, a `int&&` will not be deduced, so the `dynamic_cast` fails.

Should I make some amendment to `Method::Invoke`? If so, How? Or there is a different solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should use *perfect-forwarding* via [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), otherwise your rvalue/lvalue references won't likely be retained (for more informations [see this beautiful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3582313/493122)):

```
void Invoke(Args&&... args)
//              ^^
{ method(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^
```

and then:

```
template<typename ...Args>
void Invoke(Args&&... args)
{
    auto pHolder = dynamic_cast<MethodHolder<Args&&...>*>(pBase);
    //                                           ^^
    if (pHolder)
        pHolder->Invoke(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
//                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    ^
}
```

Comment: How about `func` take a `int` parameter? My understanding: `Args` will be deduced `int`, and the `dynamic_cast` fails.